# Rails migration collation for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, collation

I just noticed that my recent migration created tables with collation of latin1_swedish_ci instead of utf8_unicode_ci.
It used to create utf8_unicode_ci.
My database.yml has encoding: utf8 and I assume all tables I create will have utf8.

My dev machine works fine but my production on a shared hosting has this problem.

Why did this happen?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

You can force migrations with these options `TYPE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci` to choose the encoding, or change the default charset of your mysql server.